# On windows graphviz is not working even after pip install or conda. It says InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

On windows graphviz is not working even after `pip install` or `conda`. It says

> InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found.

I am trying to model with decision trees.

```
 dot_data = StringIO()
 export_graphviz(dt, out_file=dot_data, 
                     filled=True, rounded=True,
                 feature_names=X.columns.values,
                 class_names = ['human','bot'],
                     special_characters=True)  
 graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
 Image(graph.create_png())`
```

Comment: Report back software version by updating your question. No need to put it in comments. Any error-logs to share?

Comment: Have you installed the actual Graphviz application (not python module, which uses it)? https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

Comment: please search the site for "graphviz conda" probably you will find some useful hints.